# strange behaviour after orientation change

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-orientation

I hope someone could help.

I have a bit hard to explain activtiy, its a classic view pager, but has a button in the action bar which makes the view to go right and bring to sight the menu (originaly hidden out of the screen). it's a facebook like menu. I have 2 layout for that (menu and pager) and I use a custom ScrollView to get the behaviour I look for.

when i change the orientation, i want the menu to be out every time. So I created a different layout, and test the orientation on the onCreate method.

I had several try :
without configChange in the manifest, the app crashes with an "IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed" pointing to the line "mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);".

with config change, the app does crap when it rotate, it doesn't change the layout to the one in layout-land..

with config change and the content of the onCreate on the "onConfigurationChanged" it is good from portrait to landscape but the inverse goes wrong (the view is large as it should be high and as high as it should be large)...

I hope it will be less confusing for one of you.

I can post code if you want, but there is a lot of it, and I dont know which specific part would help you (just ask me).

Thanks !

[image: when i pass from portrait to landscape with the 2de try]

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_pager_layout);

    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    me = this;

    View v = findViewById(R.id.landscape);
    if (v == null) {
        isLand = false;

        scrollView = (MyHorizontalScrollView) inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.horz_scroll_layout, null);

        setContentView(scrollView);

        menu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_pager_menu_layout, null);
        app = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_pager_layout, null);

        final View[] children = new View[] { menu, app };
        int scrollToViewIdx = 1;
        TextView tv = (TextView) app.findViewById(R.id.sizerTV);
        scrollView.initViews(children, scrollToViewIdx,
                new SizeCallbackForMenu(tv));

    } else {
        isLand = true;
        menu = findViewById(R.id.main_pager_land_menu);
        app = findViewById(R.id.main_pager_land_app);
        // scrollView = new MyHorizontalScrollView(null);
    }
    // Menu INIT
    new MenuBehaviour(me, menu, inflater);
    // AppBarInit
    initializeAppBar();

    // DAO
    controlDAO = new Controller(me);
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            arrayEvent = controlDAO.ebdd.getAllEvent();
            if (arrayEvent != null) {
                runOnUiThread(onUiThread);
            } else {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(
                                me,
                                me.getResources().getString(
                                        R.string.error_no_database_yet),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }).start();

    // WS
    final AQuery aq = new AQuery(me);
    aq.ajax(uriTest, JSONObject.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONObject json, AjaxStatus status) {
            if (json != null) {
                // Toast.makeText(aq.getContext(), status.getCode() + ":" +
                // json.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                try {
                    JSONArray array = json.getJSONObject("events")
                            .getJSONArray("event");

                    controlDAO.ebdd.open();
                    // On met le nouveau flux dans la BDD
                    controlDAO.updateBDD(array);
                    // On récupere les event de la BDD (au cas ou on gererai
                    // les maj)
                    arrayEvent = controlDAO.ebdd.getAllEvent();
                    controlDAO.ebdd.close();
                    runOnUiThread(onUiThread);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        aq.getContext(),
                        "Error:"
                                + status.getCode()
                                + ", connectez vous pour acceder aux mis a jours",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

Runnable onUiThread = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        arrtype = new ArrayList<String>();

        arrtype.add("tout les evenements");
        arrtype.add("sport");
        arrtype.add("concert");
        arrtype.add("spectacle");
        arrtype.add("visite");
        controlDAO.ebdd.close();
        // On sépare les évenements en fonction de leurs type et on rempli
        // arrayOfEventByType
        arrayOfEventByType = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Event>>();
        // ajout d'une arraylist pour tout les evenements
        arrayOfEventByType.add(new ArrayList<Event>()); // tout les
                                                        // evenements
        arrayOfEventByType.add(new ArrayList<Event>()); // sport
        arrayOfEventByType.add(new ArrayList<Event>()); // concert
        arrayOfEventByType.add(new ArrayList<Event>()); // spectacle
        arrayOfEventByType.add(new ArrayList<Event>()); // visite
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayEvent.size(); i++) {
            if (!arrtype.contains(arrayEvent.get(i).type.toLowerCase())) {
                arrayOfEventByType.add(new ArrayList<Event>());
                arrtype.add(arrayEvent.get(i).type.toLowerCase());
            }

            Log.i("renaud", "arrtype.size() = " + arrtype.size());
            Log.i("renaud", "arrayOfEventByType.size() = "
                    + arrayOfEventByType.size());

            arrayOfEventByType.get(
                    arrtype.indexOf(arrayEvent.get(i).type.toLowerCase()))
                    .add(arrayEvent.get(i));
            arrayOfEventByType.get(0).add(arrayEvent.get(i));
        }
        // Test
        Log.i("renaud",
                "arrayOfEventByType.size() : " + arrayOfEventByType.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfEventByType.size(); i++) {
            Log.i("renaud", "arrayOfEventByType.get(" + i + ").length() : "
                    + arrayOfEventByType.get(i).size());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfEventByType.size(); i++) {
            if (arrayOfEventByType.get(i).isEmpty()) {
                arrayOfEventByType.remove(i);
                arrtype.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
        // ArrayList<Event> tous = arrayOfEventByType.remove(0);
        // Collections.sort(arrayOfEventByType, new EventSort());
        // arrayOfEventByType.add(0, tous);
        // // On crée un nombre de panneau en fonction des types

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                arrayOfEventByType, arrtype);
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        try {
            mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

            // +pour rajouter un titre etc..
            mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {

                    // Omniture
                    if (arg0 == 0) {
                        StadeDeFranceActivity.s.pageName = "Main Pager all event";
                    } else if (!arrayOfEventByType.isEmpty()
                            && arrayOfEventByType.get(arg0) != null
                            && !arrayOfEventByType.get(arg0).isEmpty()
                            && arrayOfEventByType.get(arg0).get(0) != null
                            && arrayOfEventByType.get(arg0).get(0).type != null) {

                        StadeDeFranceActivity.s.pageName = "Main Pager number "
                                + arg0
                                + " category:"
                                + arrayOfEventByType.get(arg0).get(0).type;
                    } else {
                        StadeDeFranceActivity.s.pageName = "Main Pager number "
                                + arg0;
                    }
                    // StadeDeFranceActivity.s.track();

                    Log.i("renaud", "page " + arg0);

                };

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
};

public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<Event>> arrayOfEventByType;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayOfname;

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm,
            ArrayList<ArrayList<Event>> arrayOfEventByType,
            ArrayList<String> arrayOfname) {
        super(fm);
        this.arrayOfEventByType = arrayOfEventByType;
        this.arrayOfname = arrayOfname;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayOfEventByType.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        return MainPagerFragment.newInstance(
                arrayOfEventByType.get(position), arrtype.get(position));

    }

    // private ArrayList<Event> concatArray(
    // ArrayList<ArrayList<Event>> arrayOfEventByType2) {
    // ArrayList<Event> concatArray = new ArrayList<Event>();
    //
    // for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfEventByType2.size(); i++) {
    // concatArray.addAll(arrayOfEventByType2.get(i));
    // }
    //
    // return concatArray;
    // }

}

static class SizeCallbackForMenu implements SizeCallback {
    int btnWidth;
    View btnSlide;

    public SizeCallbackForMenu(View btnSlide) {
        super();
        this.btnSlide = btnSlide;
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        btnWidth = btnSlide.getMeasuredWidth();
        System.out.println("btnWidth=" + btnWidth);
    }

    @Override
    public void getViewSize(int idx, int w, int h, int[] dims) {
        dims[0] = w;
        dims[1] = h;
        final int menuIdx = 0;
        if (idx == menuIdx) {
            dims[0] = w - btnWidth;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu2) {

    if (!isLand) {
        int menuWidth = menu.getMeasuredWidth();

        // Ensure menu is visible
        menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        if (!menuDisplayed) {
            // Scroll to 0 to reveal menu
            int left = 0;
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);
        } else {
            // Scroll to menuWidth so menu isn't on screen.
            int left = menuWidth;
            scrollView.smoothScrollTo(left, 0);
        }
        menuDisplayed = !menuDisplayed;
    }
    return true;

}

public class EventSort implements Comparator<ArrayList<Event>> {
    ArrayList<String> cattab;

    public EventSort() {
        cattab = new ArrayList<String>();
        cattab.add("sport");
        cattab.add("rugby");
        cattab.add("concert");
        cattab.add("spectacle");
        cattab.add("visite");
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(ArrayList<Event> lhs, ArrayList<Event> rhs) {

        if (lhs.isEmpty()) {
            if (rhs.isEmpty()) {
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else if (rhs.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            String typelhs = lhs.get(0).type;
            String typerhs = rhs.get(0).type;
            if (cattab.indexOf(typelhs) < cattab.indexOf(typerhs)) {
                return 1;
            } else if (cattab.indexOf(typelhs) > cattab.indexOf(typerhs)) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

thats the code with no configchange in the manifest, and i catch the error in order that my app don't crash

Comment: Post your code, and screen shot also.

Comment: Did you try to use a Fragment for each part of the layout? So you could just hide the Fragment on orientation change.

Comment: i can't see why it would solve it, could you explain me why this method would be better that the other ? 
By the way, if I take off the configchange on the manifest, and that i catch the exception, the app seems to work fine.. But it warn me a bit to let this kind of potential pain in the ass problem

Answer (score 0):

When the screen orientation changes, Android will destroy your Activity and create it again.
So if your Adapter is holding references to the Activity (such as the fragment manager perhaps), that causes an error.